# 3D Secure and Core PHP and Curl

Tags: payment-gateway, 3d-secure

I am trying to integrating payment gateway with 3D Secure. I am using curl to send request with payment info include(Card detail, bill, shipping detail etc).

I am stuck to integrate with 3D Secure, I am using centinal for 3D Secure. but i am not getting how to integrate it eith existing payment gateway.

Can anyone help me with example code.

Answer (score 3):

I got my answer, i hope it can other : 3D-Secure is completely different entity most of the time if you will use any payment gateway which has 3D Secure as 3rd party. I am using cardinal commerce 3D Secure. So first you have to take response from 3dsecure and based on that response you have to call then payment gateway with 3d success or unsuccess value attach with it. Thats all i got confused with merging whereas both are separate entity. Keep it in mind. Code from 3D Secure and payment gateway will be separate and provided by their company.

Comment: Hi , Can you share some code for Curl 3D secure call - I am trying to do the same but getting error message